# CMake CUDA separate compilation static lib link error on Windows but not on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I am using CMake to compile a CUDA project, which contains a static lib and a main file. MWE [here](https://gist.github.com/8f1dbffd0f28010bced69ea8c08a751c). The directory is:

`├── CMakeLists.txt
 ├── src
     ├── mylib.h
     ├── mylib.cu
 ├── test
     ├── CMakeLists.txt
     ├── main.cpp`

On Ubuntu everything works fine. But on Windows I got a link error:

```
mylib.lib(mylib.cu.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_40_tmpxft_00006024_00000000_7_mylib_cpp1_ii_935b38c5 referenced in function "void __cdecl __sti____cudaRegisterAll(void)" (?__sti____cudaRegisterAll@@YAXXZ)\build\test\Release\main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

This issue only relates to the first `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(MyTest LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

# check requirements
find_package(CUDA   8.0 REQUIRED)

# set include and link directories
if (UNIX)
    set(CUDA_SAMPLE_INC ${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}/samples/common/inc)
    set(CUDA_TARGET_INC ${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}/targets/x86_64-linux/include)
    set(CUDA_SAMPLE_LKN ${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}/targets/x86_64-linux/lib)
endif (UNIX)
if (WIN32)
    set(CUDA_SAMPLE_INC C:/ProgramData/NVIDIA\ Corporation/CUDA\ Samples/v9.0/common/inc)
    set(CUDA_TARGET_INC C:/Program\ Files/NVIDIA GPU\ Computing\ Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/include)
    set(CUDA_SAMPLE_LKN C:/Program\ Files/NVIDIA\ GPU\ Computing\ Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/lib/x64)
endif (WIN32)
include_directories(src ${CUDA_SAMPLE_INC} ${CUDA_TARGET_INC})
link_directories(${CUDA_SAMPLE_LKN})

# define and compile our static library 
set(STATIC_MY_LIB mylib)
add_library(${STATIC_MY_LIB} STATIC src/mylib.cu)

# install
install(TARGETS ${STATIC_MY_LIB}
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

# comment it out to suppress the error
set_target_properties( ${STATIC_MY_LIB} PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

# add our test project
add_subdirectory(test)
```

If I comment out `set_target_properties( ${STATIC_MY_LIB} PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)`, the link error is gone.

Environments:

- Ubuntu 16.04, gcc 5.4, Tesla Titan X, CUDA 9.1, CMake 3.10.1
- Windows 10, VS 2015, K20c, CUDA 9.0, CMake 3.10.1

I have tried suggestions in [1](https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/17827243/register.html), [2](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/525616/question-about-___cudaregisterlinkedbinary-referenced-in-function-____cudaregisterall/?offset=3#3942819). But none of them works.

Why this happens? And how to overcome?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm struggling with this too.

Comment: @JAustin unfortunately no. I disabled the cuda separate compilation option finally.

Comment: I actually think I figured out how to do it (for future reference). In CMake, try setting CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS, i.e. set_target_properties(Loch PROPERTIES CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS ON). If it's still an issue for you, let me know if that works.

Comment: @JAustin Thanks it works! Would you mind just copy your comment to the answer so that I can accept your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After struggling with this issue for several days, I think I have found a solution. When creating the static library using CMake, set CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS, i.e. with

`set_target_properties(your_project PROPERTIES CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS ON)`

According to [this](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/building-cuda-applications-cmake/) article from Nvidia, this setting forces CMake to compile and link all CUDA symbols (function calls and the like) when the library is built.

> If you need separable compilation device linking to occur before
>   consumption by a shared library or executable,you can explicitly
>   request CMake to invoke device linking by setting the target property
>   CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS